# Notification on Windows not displaying while using toast

Tags: python, windows, toast

I have built an program that sends notification when a certain price is crossed, but while using toast its not sending any notification to display

When I tested with:

```
from winotify import Notification

notification = Notification ('Test Notification', title='Hello', msg='This is a test notification.')
notification.show()
```

it was okay.
but main code is not displaying, just showing the stock prices:

```
import os
import time
import yfinance as yf
from winotify import Notification, audio

tickers = ['AAPL', 'META', 'NVDA', 'GS', 'WFC']
upper_limits = [170, 450, 500, 450, 100]
lower_limits = [150, 440, 350, 300, 35]

while True:
    last_prices = [yf.Ticker(ticker).history(period="1d")['Close'].iloc[-1] for ticker in tickers]
    print(last_prices)
    time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(len(tickers)):
        if last_prices[i] > upper_limits[i]:
            toast = Notification('Stock Alarm Bot',
                                 title='Price Alert ' + tickers[i],
                                 msg=f'{tickers[i]} has reached a price of {last_prices[i]}. You might want to sell.',
                                 icon=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'alert_red.png'),
                                 duration='long')

            toast.add_actions(label='Go To XTB',
                              launch='https://xstation5.xtb.com/?branch=pl&_ga=2.223201755.1920106019.1692334076-2008092090.1692334076&_gl=1*1blay5h*_ga*MjAwODA5MjA5MC4xNjkyMzM0MDc2*_ga_CBPL72L2EC*MTY5MjMzNDA3Ni4xLjEuMTY5MjMzNDA5NS4wLjAuMA..#/_/login')
            toast.set_audio(audio.LoopingAlarm6, loop=True)
            toast.show()
        elif last_prices[i] < lower_limits[i]:
            toast = Notification('Stock Alarm Bot',
                                 title='Price Alert ' + tickers[i],
                                 msg=f'{tickers[i]} has reached a price of {last_prices[i]}. You might want to buy.',
                                 icon=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'alert_green.png'),
                                 duration='long')

            toast.add_actions(label='Go To XTB',
                              launch='https://xstation5.xtb.com/?branch=pl&_ga=2.223201755.1920106019.1692334076-2008092090.1692334076&_gl=1*1blay5h*_ga*MjAwODA5MjA5MC4xNjkyMzM0MDc2*_ga_CBPL72L2EC*MTY5MjMzNDA3Ni4xLjEuMTY5MjMzNDA5NS4wLjAuMA..#/_/login')
            toast.set_audio(audio.LoopingAlarm8, loop=True)
            toast.show()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are you sure the conditions are met? What if you make a toast in a else statement?

Comment: just checked and else also is not working. Yes the conditions are met, as AAPL price downloaded is 174 and upper limit is 170

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproductible example not depending on network connexion. Also, you may want to check if the data types in last_prices are integers/float as you seem to expect.

Comment: no error message

Comment: here is the example, but there also no notifications come, i think i am doing something wrong with the toast:

Comment: ```while True:
    # Simulating fetching stock prices (replace with actual data fetching)
    last_prices = [random.uniform(100, 600) for _ in tickers]
    print(last_prices)
    time.sleep(1)```  rest should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on the answer, here is code that triggers the notifications. However, not that I do not know what the problem is/was on your side. (I am writting this question because so much code is unreadable in a comment).

Also note that I removed all the stuff about using an image in the notification (because I did not have any image available).

```
import os
import time
from winotify import Notification
import random

tickers = ['AAPL', 'META', 'NVDA', 'GS', 'WFC']
upper_limits = [170, 450, 500, 450, 100]
lower_limits = [150, 440, 350, 300, 35]

while True:     
    # Simulating fetching stock prices (replace with actual data fetching)     
    last_prices = [random.uniform(100, 600) for _ in tickers]
    print(last_prices)
    time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(len(last_prices)):
      if last_prices[i] > upper_limits[i]:
          toast = Notification('Stock Alarm Bot',
                               title='Price Alert ' + tickers[i],
                               msg=f'{tickers[i]} has reached a price of {last_prices[i]}. You might want to sell.',
                               duration='long')
          toast.show()
      elif last_prices[i] < lower_limits[i]:
          toast = Notification('Stock Alarm Bot',
                               title='Price Alert ' + tickers[i],
                               msg=f'{tickers[i]} has reached a price of {last_prices[i]}. You might want to buy.',
                               duration='long')
          toast.show()
      time.sleep(1)
```